# Large bounded degree expanders in the hypercube

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Does the $n$ dimensional hypercube graph contain large bounded degree expanders as subgraphs? For example, of exponential size in $n$?

If not, one could relax the problem and allow the maximum degree and the expansion constant to grow with $n$. How fast should these grow so that exponential size examples can be found?

Comment: Lemma 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00409 gives an upper bound on the edge expansion of bounded-degree subgraphs of the hypercube.